# The cardinality of the union of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The finite union of finite sets is finite. The countable union of countable sets is countable. More generally, is true that if $I$ is an index set of cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, and $I$ and $X_i$ have same cardinality for every $i$, then the set:
$$X=\bigcup_{i \in I}X_i. $$
Has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: For the finite case, "finite" is not a cardinality, so that does not work, strictly speaking.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni, sure but the question still makes sense if we divide sets in classes of finite, countable, etc..., and then ask the classes to be closed under union as above. it just makes the phrasing terrible.

Comment: It's a direct consequence of the fact that $\mathfrak{c}+\mathfrak{c}=\mathfrak{c}$

Comment: @Sam but this is not going to be a finite sum, I don't know if we can freely apply the fact you mentioned.

Comment: @Alessandro Sorry, I meant $\mathfrak{c}\times\mathfrak{c}=\mathfrak{c}$